# How to fully close tkinter-app?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Following code is given:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.destroy)
        self.quitButton.grid()


app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

When running this code a small window appears with a QUIT-Button in it. The button disappears when pressed but the window stays. 
How to close the window and the app with that Button-click?

Comment: Replace `self.destroy` with `self.master.destroy`. `Self` is just a frame, while the root window is a `master` (implicitly, since you pass `None`)!

Comment: ouh! ups. Thank you very much.

Comment: The short answer is to call `.destroy()` on the root window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking `self.master.destroy` in you code which will destroy the window by pressing on the button `Quit`

```
import tkinter as tk


class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quitButton.grid()


app = Application()
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```